# Find all solutions to the congruence relation

Tags: number-theory, polynomials, modular-arithmetic

Let $p$ be a prime and $d$ is a divisor of $p-1$
 Let $a$ be an integer that is not divisible by $p$, and suppose $a$ has order $d \pmod p$. List all solutions to $x^d -1 \equiv 0\pmod p$

My attempt $a$ has order $d$ means $a^d \equiv 1 \pmod p$

 I know that $x^d -1 \equiv 0\pmod p$ has at most $d$ solutions $\pmod p$

I seem to be stuck after this. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some choices that solve $x^d-1\equiv 0\pmod p$ that can be spotted directly.  Notice that for any integer $k$, $a^k$ solves the equivalence.  More precisely,

$(a^k)^d\equiv (a^d)^k\equiv 1^k\equiv 1\pmod p.$

Now, it is straight-forward to prove that for $k=1,\dots,d$, the values of $a^k$ are distinct (hint: use contradiction and the fact that $a$ has order $d$).

Comment: Excuse me, what does your profile picture represent ?